# Is it possible to define a service in a libraries manifest without also defining it in the hosts manifest?

Tags: android

I have a library that contains a subclass of the Android Application class. The sub-class contains a method that launches a service (also contained in the library project).

When I include the library in my host application, the activity manager complains that it is unable to start the service intent (not found).

The code structure is:

#### Libraries manifest:

```
<service name="com.my.project.MyService" />
```

#### Application subclass within library:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
startService(intent);
```

I can resolve the issue by defining the service again in the host applications manifest; However, I would prefer not to impose this requirement on developers using the library.

My question is, can I avoid the requirement for referencing the libraries service in the hosts manifest?

Comment: Nope you cannot. Check out [Declaring library components in the the manifest file](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO

At least As Far as I Know.  You need to declare it in the manifest for it to be active.

You can register receivers programatically . That you can google out.

Answer (score 1):

Worth mentioning, though it won't affect you as of your current implementation (if I read it correctly), is that one should pay attention to which `Context` one passes on to the `Intent` constructor.

If you for example decide to move your `Service` to a separate APK, that service won't be found in the client applications `Context`.

You could then instead use an alternative `Intent` constructor:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.my.service.project", "com.my.service.project.MyService");
```

Or add a `BroadcastReceiver` to the `com.my.service.project` project which then is triggered from the client application by a `sendBroadcast` instead of `startService`.